# Use ui-router in ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

A plunkr of my issue is available [here](http://embed.plnkr.co/5C0a2y7ZedlOs1O51lOx/preview).

I want to implement the following behaviour : when I click on a link, this element, and only this one, should switch to the "header.profiles" version.
i.e. I would like to achieve the following :

```
   sub template of settings
   Go to profile
   Go to profile
   Go to profile
```

And not what currently happens :

```
   sub template of settings
   sub template of settings
   sub template of settings
   sub template of settings
```

How can I do it ?

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: I don't know how I do. Please help me